# Better proof that if $A$ and $B$ are in the Event Space ($F$) then $A-B\in F$?

Tags: probability-theory, alternative-proof

I have a proof that if $A$ and $B$ are in the Event Space ($F$) then $A-B\in F$. However, I don't think it's very elegant. Do people have another proof that is perhaps more elegant?

Here is the proof:
$A,B \in F $

$\implies A \cup B \in F$ ... ($X_1,X_2,\in F \implies X_1\cup X_2\in F$)

$\implies (S-A)\cup B \in F$ ... ($X\in F\implies S-A \in F$)

$\implies S - [(S-A)\cup B] \in F$ ... ($X\in F\implies S-A \in F$)

$\implies A\cap (S-B) \in F$ ... (by DeMorgan's Law)

$\implies A-B \in F$

Thank you!

Comment: The proof is correct and since you are using the basic properties of a $\sigma$-algebra it's hard to remove any lines. However, you could have a separate proof that first shows that a $\sigma$-algebra is also closed under intersections. Then it's just a oneliner: $A,B\in\mathcal F$. Then $S-B\in\mathcal F$ (by your separate proof), and hence $A-B = A\cap(S-B) \in\mathcal F$. You can also polish notation a bit by writing $A^\complement$ (or any other symbol that's commonly used to denote complements) instead of $S-A$.

Comment: Understood. Thank you @Quertiopler !